# Router changes URL without changing the component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I have a spreadsheet page, which returns a component from the react-spreadsheet npm library:

```
import Link from "next/link"
import { useState } from "react"

import { Spreadsheet as Sheet } from "react-spreadsheet"

const Spreadsheet = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState<{ value: "" }[][]>([
    [{ value: "" }, { value: "" }, { value: "" }],
    [{ value: "" }, { value: "" }, { value: "" }],
  ])

  return (
    <div>
      {data && <Sheet data={data} onChange={setData} />}
    </div>
  )
}

export default Spreadsheet
```

After editing a cell, no other page components will render without refreshing or loading pages manually.

Navbar component:

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router"
import Link from "next/link"
import classes from "./Navbar.module.css"

const Navbar = () => {
  const router = useRouter()

  return (
    <nav className={classes.navbar}>
      <Link href="/">
        <a className={classes.logo}>Logo</a>
      </Link>
      <div className={classes.rightSideWrapper}>
        <Link href="/spreadsheet">
          <a>New Spreadsheet</a>
        </Link>
        <Link href="/saved">
          <a>Saved</a>
        </Link>
      </div>
    </nav>
  )
}

export default Navbar
```

Layout component:

```
import Navbar from "../Navbar/Navbar"

interface Children {
  children: JSX.Element
}

const Layout = ({ children }: Children) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar />
      {children}
    </div>
  )
}

export default Layout
```

_app.tsx:

```
import "../styles/globals.css"
import type { AppProps } from "next/app"
import Layout from "../components/Layout/Layout"
import NoteContextProvider from "../contexts/NoteContext"

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  return (
    <NoteContextProvider>
      <Layout>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </Layout>
    </NoteContextProvider>
  )
}

export default MyApp
```

If I do `console.log('changed')` inside of _app.tsx, it says changed twice (once for the component change, once for the props I'm assuming?) but as soon as I edit the spreadsheet, those updates stop, but the url still changes.

I've narrowed it down to the `onChange` prop passed into `<Sheet />`. If I remove the onChange, I can edit, but it allows me to still move around freely.

There is also a type error on the `onChange` prop:

[image: onChange prop type error]

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the type error, you might have to wrap the `setState` call like so:

```
<Sheet data={data} onChange={(data) => {setData(data)}} />
```